# how to update/insert a specified row in the table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that gives me output which looks like this:

```
date|count|highest 
---------------------
mon | 20  | null
tue | 32  | null
wed | 45  | null
thu | 14  | null
fri | 74  | null
sat | 12  | null
sun | 32  | null
```

Now, I need to run a query that picks the highest value from "count" and replaces the null with that value as below:

```
date|count|highest 
---------------------
mon | 20  | null
tue | 32  | null
wed | 45  | null
thu | 14  | null
fri | 74  | 74
sat | 12  | null
sun | 32  | null
```

Can anyone help please?

**EDIT: the highest column is not a physical column in the table but it's an output from the select statement. So I don't want to to update the table.**

**Query I use:**

```
select date_format(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') as date, count, "null" as highest
    from Table_A
    where (timestamp >= (now() - interval 24 hour)) 
    group by date  
    order by date desc
```

*don't worry about the "date"

Comment: Can you share the current sql you have?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table_name
SET highest = COUNT
WHERE id IN
    (SELECT id
     FROM table_name
     ORDER BY COUNT DESC LIMIT 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use sub query

```
UPDATE table1 SET highest = 74 WHERE count = (SELECT Max(Count) FROM table2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax and let me know if it works!

```
UPDATE table_name 
 SET highest = 74 
  WHERE count = (SELECT max(count) FROM table_name)
```

or

```
UPDATE table_name 
 SET highest = (SELECT max(count) FROM table_name) 
  WHERE count = (SELECT max(count) FROM table_name)
```

dont want to update and just wanted to get the highest

```
SELECT * 
 FROM table_name 
  WHERE count = (SELECT max(count) FROM table_name)
```

try this

```
SELECT date, count, IF(count= (SELECT max(count) FROM table_name), (SELECT max(count) FROM table_name), 'null') AS highest FROM table_name WHERE count = (SELECT max(count) FROM table_name)
```

Cheers!

Comment: can you give me the sql statement you have?

Comment: because as i read your question this is the solution i can give.

Comment: As my understanting with the question you want to get the highest value from your table and the column is count (which is stated above) then update this data setting the null value which is the highest column to 74 or any number you want.

Comment: query posted in the question

Comment: not just the highest value. I need to be able to run the query which will populate the same output as per my question"second table". I need to see all the nulls as well as the highest value.

Answer (score 0):

To Update a specified row in the table

UPDATE table_name SET field1=value1, field2=value2 WHERE  field_n=some_value;

To Delete a specified row in the table

DELETE FROM table_name WHERE field1=some_value;